# How do I make a welcome screen in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to add a screen to my app that will be only displayed the first time when the app is launched. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 11):

You can keep a variable in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In your first view controller's `viewDidLoad` method check that variable and create the welcome screen and add it as a subview to the controller's view. Once its displayed you set the variable to 1 in `NSUserDefaults`.

This will display that screen first time when it's launched. If app is deleted then the next install will have the `NSUserDefaults` value cleared off. I hope this helps you.
If you dont get the documentation of `NSUserDefaults`, which is fairly simple, drop a comment and I will write up a piece of code for you.

Comment: @apptunes There's plenty here to go on. If you can't come up with the code to do this, you're going to have a hard time writing an app.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the code, here's what I use;

```
#define kAppHasRunBeforeKey @"appFirstTimeRun"
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kAppHasRunBeforeKey] boolValue]) { 
    //put your welcome code here
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kAppHasRunBeforeKey];
}
```

That will ensure that the welcome code is only run the first time your app runs across this code. Put this in your main view controller's `viewDidLoad` method and add your own welcome code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for splash screen-an image displayed at app start-up

Here is a nice tutorial about this:

[iPhone Tutorial for Creating a Splash Screen](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/)